# Does the texture parameter GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP only update the area of the texture that is updated?

Tags: opengl

I'm supporting an old version of OpenGL. Unlike 3.0 where I can control things with `glGenerateMipmap` I am unsure about using GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP properly.

I have a texture atlas and I'm bringing subsections of it into and out of existence. I need to support OpenGL 2.0 so I don't always have access to the newer features.

My worry is that by setting GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP to true, every time I update, say, 64x64 out of something like 4096x4096, it will rebuild everything. It would be much nicer if I could determine whether or not it only updates the areas that would be affected by the write. The [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml) doesn't indicate when mipmap generation is run with GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP unless I missed it.

Then this also raises a question of whether or not mipmap generation is run upon turning on the flag, or only after some kind of texture data upload happens. For example, suppose I want to batch upload a 50 of these 64x64 blocks. Would I turn it off, upload, then turn it back on? Or would I upload 49, then turn it on, and upload the last 1 to cause it to regenerate mipmaps?

Comment: If you need that fine-grain level of control, consider generating the mipmaps yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glGenerateMipmap` was created to deal with all of these issues caused by `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAPS`. If you don't have access to it, the only thing you can do to avoid these problems is build the mipmaps yourself. And that's going to be hard on the GPU, since you don't have FBOs (`glGenerateMipmap` is part of every FBO extension, so if you don't have access to that, you don't have access to FBOs).

So it would have to be done on the CPU.